# Azure Function App to run "az graph query"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app

I need suggestions on how to use azure function app to run "az graph query" in Azure under a resource group and then store the output into storage or keyvault secrets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use powershell function and use the cli command.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a CLI command is not supported by Azure function as of now. You can have a look at [`supported languages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages).Instead you can use Azure automation if you are looking to automate Azure operations, have you looked at [`Azure Automation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro)

Comment: No it is not supported either

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute Azure CLI commands in Azure Functions but Azure functions support Powershell Core. So you can use `Search-AzGraph` command to get the required data and store it in Storage account or Keyvault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resourcegraph/search-azgraph?view=azps-3.4.0

Comment: No. Functions with powershell or Automation accounts or Azure REST API. You can invoke automation runbook from Logic app.